# Segmentation fault when free large array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, free

My code runs with no errors on small files. But I get segmfault on large inputs (millions line). Please see some of the code below:

```
element* unionFind(void *data)
{
    element *retVal = NULL;
    retVal = (element *)malloc(sizeof(element));
    retVal->data = data;
    retVal->rank = 0;
    retVal->leader = retVal;
    return retVal;
}
```

Main:
    ...

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   
char str[2048]; 
char* v_S = NULL; 
struct set *s_v = NULL;
```

*** count number of lines in input

```
long *v_L = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long)*ct_lines);
element **v = malloc(sizeof(element)*ct_lines) ;

while(fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp) != NULL)
{
     v_S = strtok(str,":");        

     v_L[i] = atol(v_S);
         v[i] = unionFind(&v_L[i]);
     s_v = add_vertex(v_L[i], v[i]);

     i++;
}

fclose(fp);

for (i = 0; i < ct_lines; i++) //Here segfault
    {
    free(v[i]); v[i] = NULL;
    }

free(v); v = NULL;
free(v_L); v_L = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Side note: when you write `retVal = (element *)malloc(sizeof(element));`, you are repeating the type of `retVal` which is not good. Especially if you decide to change its type. The use `malloc` is: `type *var = malloc(size * sizeof(*var));` which is shorter, clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: `element **v = malloc(sizeof(element)*ct_lines) ;` should be `element **v = malloc(sizeof(element*)*ct_lines) ;`

Comment: @newacct that was it!! thanks a lotttttt!!!

Comment: @Nellie: but that's shouldn't be a problem, because `element` (a struct containing several things) is than `element *` (a pointer), and so you should just have allocated too much space, which shouldn't cause a crash

Answer (score 0):

after each malloc you should check whether malloc has returned NULL( which means memory could not be allocated as heap is full). If it returns NULL, generally error message is printed.   And  if still you want to allocate memory you will have to retry after freeing up some already allocated memory.

As your program fails for large files, no need of reading code in detail, it must be failing since its running out of free memory and malloc is returning NULL and then you are trying to save structure elements at NULL address in top function findUnion.